# how to generate .dzn file using R or python in minizinc

Tags: minizinc

I mostly use R and python for data analysis.

How do I use R or python or other general purpose language to generate .dzn file  for minizinc model

Answer (score 5):

Although `.dzn` files are the traditional data entry files for MiniZinc models, newer versions of the MiniZinc driver can use JSON. Both R and Python can easily generate JSON from data. An example to generate JSON data for the following model, `model.mzn`:

```
int: n;
array[1..n] of bool: arr;
float: f;
```

Exporting simple python data:

```
import json

data = {
    "n": 4,
    "arr": [True, False, False, True],
    "f": 2.75,
}

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

This python script will create a file `data.json` containing the data. MiniZinc can now directly use the generated file: `minizinc --solver gecode model.mzn data.json`

Comment: The manual chapter is [2.1.3. Datafiles and Assertions](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.2.0/en/modelling.html?highlight=datafiles). [4.1.13. JSON support](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.2.0/en/spec.html?highlight=include#json-support). A simple alternative might be to generate your own `*.mzn` file and use an `include statement`.

Comment: @Dekker1 How to write array2d in json?

Comment: You can just write it as an array of arrays, for example: `{ "x": [[1,2,3],[3,4,5]]}`

Answer (score 1):

The pymzn package supports converting python dicts to dzn files: http://paolodragone.com/pymzn/reference/dzn/index.html

An example may look something like

```
from pymzn import dzn
data = {
    "n": 4,
    "arr": [True, False, False, True],
    "f": 2.75,
}
with open("example.dzn", "w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(dzn.dict2dzn(data)))
```

The contents of example.dzn will then be:

```
n = 4;
arr = array1d(1..4, [true, false, false, true]);
f = 2.75;
```